# Why doesn't the modifier "in" work for arrays?

Tags: c#, c#-10.0

I wrote some code to check the keyword "in" (C#). Add I know that "in" means that parameter will be readonly. But it works for functions with parameters type int, double, etc, but not for int[], double[], etc.

So, I write this code, and I didn't see Error on line `arr1[i] += 1;`. It's amazing. Can someone please explain why?

```
static int summArray(in int[] arr1, in int[] arr2, int length) 
{
    int summ = 0;

    if (arr1.Length >= length && arr2.Length >= length) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            arr1[i] += 1;
            summ += arr1[i];
            summ += arr2[i];
        }
        return summ;
    }
    throw new ArgumentException("too small array!");
}
```

Comment: `readonly` means you cannot reassign the variable, it doesn't mean you cannot modify the refered object (or array in this case)

Comment: If you want the content of the array to not be changed use [`IReadOnlyCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlycollection-1?view=net-6.0) instead of `[]` and continue to use the `in` keyword. `in IReadOnlyCollection<int> arr1, in IReadOnlyCollection<int> arr2`

Comment: No, I don't want to use IReadOnlyCollection now , I want to understand how "in" works. Because when I write code like there: 

static void example(in int variable) 
        {
            variable += 3;
        }

Here I have an error "CS8331 Cannot assign to variable 'in int' because it is a readonly variable". But in my example in question (function summArray) I don't have any errors! I want to understand why.

Comment: Because you are not reassigning the array pointer. If you want to reproduce that exception the same way you do with the code you mentioned then do `arr1 = new int[0];`

Comment: I understood what do you mean.
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not just arrays; the `in` modifier will possibly surprise you in the same way for any reference type. In case it wasn't immediately obvious, arrays are reference types even if they're an array of value types. You can always modify the contents of an array, just like you can set the `.Name` of an instance of `class Person`. `in` and their brethren are only concerned with assigning to the variable reference, not changing the contents of the data referred to by the variable

> I know that "in" means that parameter will be readonly

The variable itself is readonly in the sense that it cannot be reassigned to point to something else, but it doesn't mean that the thing pointed to by the variable cannot be modified

`in` is part of a trio of markers for arguments to methods: `in`, `ref`, `out`

They are essentially used to indicate to other developers wha tthe method will do with the reference passed:

- `out` means "the method will definitely assign something to the given variable reference" (i.e. do not waste effort writing code that will supply a variable having a value because it will be replaced)
- `ref` means "the method may replace the object referred to, with another" (i.e. take care to check whether the method will replace your carefully created data with some other data, and save your own reference to your data if you don't want to risk losing it)
- `in` means "the method cannot replace the object referred to by the parameter, with a different object" (i.e. by all means take 5 minutes of CPU time to craft the perfect object; it will be passed by reference but your code won't find it swapped for something else when the method is done)

`in` is slightly different to not specifying anything at all; no specifier passes by creating a copy of the reference to the object held by the calling method. When a copy reference is supplied, the called method may point that reference to another object, but it doesn't make any difference to the caller; the called method modifies a copy so the calling method doesn't experience any change in what its reference actually refers to. For variables passed by original reference there was a risk that  the called method would swap it out for something else, meaning the caller could lose data it had prepared

```
//out: caller shouldn't supply a value; LongProcess's efforts are wasted

var x = LongProcess();
SomeOutMethod(out x); 


void SomeOutMethod(out object x){
  x = somethingelse; //must be done
}



//ref: caller should be careful if supplying a value; LongProcess's efforts may be wasted

var x = LongProcess();
var savedX = x;        //preserve my X in case...
SomeRefMethod(ref x);  //maybe this will replace x


void SomeRefMethod(ref object x){
  x = somethingelse; //may be done
}



//in: caller shouldn;t worry about supplying a value; LongProcess's efforts won't be wasted

var x = LongProcess();
SomeInMethod(in x); 


void SomeInMethod(in object x){
  x = somethingelse; //cannot be done
}
```

---

And of course none of this has any bearing on modifying the *contents* of a passed object reference

```
void ModifyIt(Person p){
  p.Name = "John";         //always possible unless Person forbids it
}

void ModifyIt(int[] x){
  x[0] = 1;                //always possible no matter what
}
```

`in/ref/out` purely relate to operations like `p = new Person...`, `x = new int10]`. The have absolutely nothing to do with `p.Name = ...` or `x[0] = ...`

Comment: I am very grateful to you for such a detailed answer !!! Now all the misunderstandings in this topic have passed for me! Thanks!!!

Comment: I think it'd be nice for `in` to be the default, but that's a breaking change.